# Find out if a path exists avoiding circular obstacles

Tags: computational-geometry, binary-search

Given

1. a rectangle defined by its corners $(0, 0)$ and $(w,h)$,
2. $n$ circles $\{ (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$ with the
   same radius $r$,

I need to determine the smallest possible radius *r* so that there is no
way to get from $(0,0)$ to $(w, h)$ without touching those circles.

What I have tried is

1. Use binary search to determine *r*
2. But the issue is that since there is no limitations for the
   coordinates of the points (e.g. for them to be integers) I can't get
   any idea how to construct a graph and use some path finding algorithm
   such as DFS.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Examples**

Example 1, $w = 15, h = 20$; circles with coordinates $(2,7)$ and $(7,3)$; the result is $d \sim 3.2016$
[image: Circles with radius]

Example 2 (without the right radius, but just to show what the issue is)
[image: Circles with different radius]

Comment: Let $A$ and $B$ be the top left and bottom right corners of the rectangle. The way if shut if you can get from $A$ to $B$ in the following graph $G$. The vertices of $G$ are $A$, $B$, intersections of circles with circles, and circles with sides of the rectangle. Two vertices $p$ and $q$ are connected by an edge if they belong to the same circle. or if $p$ is either $A$ or $B$ and $q$ is on a side of the rectangle and $p$ is the closets to $q$ among $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The graph in my previous comment can be simplified. For example, if $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ are all vertices on the same circle, then one doesn't need all the edges in the $K_n$ that they will form. It is sufficient to use the edges that are sides of their convex hull, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption using binary search is a good assumption, that means
that we can assume we know the radius, and focus only on the subproblem:

> Given a rectangle and a set of circles, is it possible to navigate in
> the rectangle from the top left corner to the bottom right corner
> without touching a circle.

If a circle is covering either the starting point or the end point, we
can abort immediately, so we'll assume they don't.

We will create a graph consisting one vertex for each circle, and one vertex for the *south east* edges of the rectangle, and one vertex for the *north west* edges of the rectangle, in other words:

$$V = \{ v_c \mid \text{$c$ is a circle} \} \cup \{v_{\text{se}}, v_{\text{nw}} \}$$

Then we create the edges as follows:

$$E = \{ e = v_{c_1} v_{c_2} \mid \text{$c_1$ and $c_2$ overlap}\} \cup \{ e = v_{c} v_{s} \mid \text{$c$ touches side $s$}\}$$

In other words an edge between two objects if they overlap
geometrically.

If the *south east* sides are connected to the *north west* sides, then
it means that **you cannot travel from the lower left part of the
rectangle to the upper right part** of the rectangle.

In other words, you only need to see whether $v_{\text{se}}$ is
connected to $v_{\text{nw}}$ in your constructed graph, which would
isolate the starting point from the end point.

---

**Yes instance**

[image: Yes instance]

**No instance** (south is connected to west)

[image: No instance, south is connected to west]

Comment: One way to simplify the cases 1,2,3 into a single one is to consider the top and left sides as a single vertex $A$ and the right and bottom sides as a single vertex $B$. Then a path doesn't exists if there is a path in the graph from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @plop thanks, that made it indeed simpler.  Updated.